# JButton accessible for several Panels

Tags: class, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm new at Java Programming and have "beginner Question". 
I already tried to find wether someone already had the same problem, but I couldn't find any posts which were on my low level.

My Problem: 
I have 2 JPanels in one of them, (let's call it Panel1) I implements a JTextField (field1) and a JButton (button1). on Panel2 I want to draw something, depending on what the using tipped in the first JTextField.

My Problem is I want Panel2 to "see" that button1 (in Panel1) , which I don't manage to do.

Can anyone give me a hint, a Youtube Video or something like that, where I can see a nice example where someone handles such a Problem?

Greetings Ventura

P.S I had an idea to pass values to Panel2 where it should draw those things I want, here my code up so far (I hope I post it correctly): Here Panel1:

```
public class Panel1 extends JPanel
{
    public JButton button = new JButton("OK");
    public JTextField field1 = new JTextField(5);
    public String name;int b;

public Panel1()
{
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);  
    add(field1);
    add(button);
    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener(field1);
    button.addActionListener(listener);  
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
    return new Dimension(400,400);
}
}
```

Here the ButtonListener :

```
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener        
{       
Graphics g;
//Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    public Panel2 pan2 = new Panel2();
    public String name;
    public JTextField field1 = new JTextField();
    int b;
    public ButtonListener(JTextField field1)
    {this.field1 = field1;} 

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
    {
        String op = e.getActionCommand();
        if(op.equals("OK"))
        {   
            name = field1.getText();
        try
            {
                b = Integer.parseInt(name);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Ihre Zahl = "+b);
                pan2.setvalue(b,g);
            }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex)  {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please enter real numbers!");}
        }
    }
    }
```

And finally Panel2 where I'd like to draw things based on the Input given in Panel1 (for example: I type in 10 and he draws me a Rectangle with width 10 or something like that)

```
public class Panel2 extends JPanel
{    
Graphics g;
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

public int b;
public Panel2()
{       
    setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g2.setColor(Color.RED);
    g2.fillRect(200, 200, 50, 50);
    Paint2(g);
}
public void Paint2(Graphics g)
{
    this.g = g;
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    //super.paintComponent(g);
    System.out.println("TEST2");
    g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    //System.out.println("TEST3");
    g2.fillRect(10 , 10, 40, 40);
}
public void setvalue(int b, Graphics g)
{
this.b = b; 
this.g = g;
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
g2.fillRect(0, 0, 40, 40);
System.out.println("B ist gleich = "+b);
//Paint2(g2);
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize()
{
return new Dimension(400,400);
}
```

I'm sorry if it is a little cumbersome to read.
My basic Problem I get in this code is the NullpointerException in Panel2 when I want to call the Method

> setvalue(int b, Graphics g)
>   g2.setColor(Color.Cyan)

Greetings Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a redesign to most of `Panel1` and a little bit to `Panel2`.

I'm going to start with Panel2 because it's simpler. Here is the new code:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel2 extends JPanel {
    Graphics g;
    Graphics2D g2;

    public int b;

    public Panel2() {
        setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
        b = 50;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g2.setColor(Color.RED);
        g2.fillRect(200, 200, 50, 50);

        g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g2.fillRect(10, 10, 40, 40);

        g2.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g2.fillRect(b, b, 40, 40);
    }

    public void setValue(int b) {
        this.b = b;
        System.out.println("B ist gleich = " + b);
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(400, 400);
    }
    }
```

The biggest change that I made to Panel2 is that I made `g2` a class variable that all the methods can use. Instead of making the methods take a Graphics variable each time, I just made it so that they can use the one from the class. I also didn't make a new Graphics2D variable "equal" anything each time the method was called because there was no need for that. The only place I updated it in was the `paintComponent()` method so that I could update it once for the whole class.

Next up is Panel1. Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Panel1 extends JPanel {
    public JButton button = new JButton("OK");
    public JTextField field1 = new JTextField(5);
    public String name;
    int b;
    private Panel2 pan2;

    public Panel1() {
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    add(field1);
    add(button);
    ActionListener listener = new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String op = e.getActionCommand();
            if (op.equals("OK")) {
                name = field1.getText();
                try {
                    b = Integer.parseInt(name);
                    pan2.setValue(b);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Ihre Zahl = " + b);
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter real numbers!");
                }
            }

        }
    };
    button.addActionListener(listener);
}

public void setSecondPanel(Panel2 panel) {
    pan2 = panel;
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(400, 400);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    Panel1 pan1 = new Panel1();
    Panel2 pan2 = new Panel2();
    pan1.setSecondPanel(pan2);
    frame.setSize(pan1.getPreferredSize().width + pan2.getPreferredSize().width, pan1.getPreferredSize().height);
    frame.add(pan2, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.add(pan1, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

First of all, notice how I didn't create a `ButtonListener`. Because you're only using it once, there's no need to create a new class for it (it's also less code).

In the `main()` method, I made it so that it adds both panels to the opposite sides so that they won't overlap each other or anything.

Finally, I created a `setSecondPanel` method in the `Panel1` class so that the class would have a `Panel2` variable to work with at any time.

Comment: Hello thank you very much for your answer. I applied your tipps and I posted the code in order to make clear where my problem is (The main method I don't post in order let it clearly arranged.

Comment: If it helped would you mind upvoting it and checking it off?

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot for your help it's very usefull :) but there is one little thing which I still don't get; probably you can help me there: I would like the code to "repaint" stuff; as you can see in Panel2 in the method "setValue" it says g2.fillRect(...) but it actually doens't paint the Rectangle in Panel1, when I'm tipping something in. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Use the repaint() method... Also, completely repaste the code because I made a few changes

Comment: No problem! Would you also mind upvoting the post if it helped (up arrow)